# How capture a keyboard input in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I compiled linux kernel and I added a message, to boot process in Main.c file:

```
pr_alert("press any key to continue..");
```

Now I need to detect when a keyboard key is pressed to continue with boot process, I know it should not be done but it's required for a homework. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: well it,s a hell of a problem since keyboard driver may not be booted at your stage and you can't use bios interrupts. It'd suggested to use kgdb for kernel debugging not 'press any key' mechanics because kernel is not an application proggram.

Comment: Thou keyboard to module communication on fully booted kernel is simple enough.

Comment: That's what happens when you do not understand your teacher. Are you sure he wasn't talking about `init.rc`?

Answer (score 0):

'Wait for key press' debugging just isn't propitiate method for kernel debugging. If you need to stop and analyze kernel data use kgdb.